# How to chain together R modules?

Tags: r, shiny, module, reactive

In the R Shiny code below, I show example code for modularizing reactive data processing. The code is housed in two separate R files: one a base App and another a module App linked to the base App. The base App sends a reactive dataframe (`df()`) and user input (`input$svc`) for multiplying the dataframe values to a separate module, the module calculates, and the module sends the output back to the base App UI for rendering as a second table.

Please note the reactive `data()` object in the module that runs the multiplication calculation. I would like to send that `data()` object to a second module in a separate R file that runs a separate calculation, such as adding a value of 10 to each dataframe cell generated by `data()`, and then send those results back to the first module for rendering in that second table via UI.

How can this be done?

Code for base App:

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)

source("C:/Users/User/Desktop/testModule1.R")

ui <- fluidPage(
  mainPanel(
    DTOutput("table"),
    sliderInput("svc", '', min = 0, max = 10, value = 1),
    allocTbl_ui("tblModule")  
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  df <- data.frame(A = 1:3, B = 4:6, C = 7:9)
  
  output$table <- renderDT({datatable(df)})
  
  allocTbl_server(
    "tblModule",
    df = reactive(df),  
    svc = reactive(input$svc)
  )
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Code for module App:

```
# Module file name: testModule1.R

allocTbl_ui <- function(id) {
  ns <- NS(id)
  DTOutput(ns("tbl"))
}

allocTbl_server <- function(id, df, svc) {
  moduleServer(id, function(input, output, session) {
    output$tbl <- renderDT({
      data <- df() * as.numeric(svc())
      datatable(data)
    })
  })
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Within your first module, create the updated data as a reactive and return it back to the app_server from where it can be passed to the third module.

```
library(DT)
# first module
allocTbl_ui <- function(id) {
    ns <- NS(id)
    DTOutput(ns("tbl"))
}
# first module server    
allocTbl_server <- function(id, df, svc) {
    moduleServer(id, function(input, output, session) {
        # store updated data as a reactive
        new_dat <- reactive({
            df() * as.numeric(svc())
        })
        output$tbl <- renderDT({
            datatable(new_dat())
        })
        # return updated data
        return(new_dat)
    })
}

# second module
mod_2_ui <- function(id){
    ns <- NS(id)
    DTOutput(ns('tbl2'))
}
# adds 10 to df and shows as DT
mod_2_server <- function(id, upd_dat2){
    moduleServer(id, function(input, output, session){
        output$tbl2 <- renderDT({
            data <- upd_dat2() + 10
            datatable(data)
        })
    })
}

ui <- fluidPage(
    mainPanel(
        DTOutput("table"),
        sliderInput("svc", '', min = 0, max = 10, value = 1),
        allocTbl_ui("tblModule"), 
        mod_2_ui('mod2') # add second module
    )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
    df <- data.frame(A = 1:3, B = 4:6, C = 7:9)
    
    output$table <- renderDT({datatable(df)})
    
    # store returned value from first module
    upd_dat <- allocTbl_server("tblModule",
                               df = reactive(df),
                               svc = reactive(input$svc))
    
    # send this returned value to second module
    mod_2_server('mod2', upd_dat)
}
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: I posted another answer below, using a function for the "addition of 10" operation instead of creating a complete module with namespace. Which approach do you prefer, in terms of processing speed and code clarity? Though the code here is very simplified, I'm trying to run one type of calculations in one R file and another type of calculations in another R file for purposes of code clarity.

Answer (score 0):

Below is another way to partly address the question, by using a function for the addition of 10 instead of using a module with namespace. This serves to "compartmentalize" the code into separate R files.

Base App:

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)

source("C:/Users/User/Desktop/testModule1.R")

ui <- fluidPage(
  mainPanel(
    DTOutput("table1"),  
    sliderInput("svc", '', min = 0, max = 10, value = 1),
    allocTbl_ui("tblModule")  
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  df <- data.frame(A = 1:3, B = 4:6, C = 7:9)
  
  output$table1 <- renderDT({
    datatable(df, caption = "Table 1")  
  })
  
  allocTbl_server(
    "tblModule",
    df = reactive(df),
    svc = reactive(input$svc)
  )
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Module 1:

```
# Module file name: testModule1.R

source("C:/Users/User/Desktop/testModule2.R")

allocTbl_ui <- function(id) {
  ns <- NS(id)
  DTOutput(ns("tbl"))
}

allocTbl_server <- function(id, df, svc) {
  moduleServer(id, function(input, output, session) {
    output$tbl <- renderDT({
      data <- cbind(A = df()[, "A", drop = FALSE], 
                    mult_A = df()[, "A"] * as.numeric(svc())
      )
      updatedData <- updateData(data, as.numeric(svc()))
      datatable(updatedData, 
                caption = "Table 2", 
                rownames = TRUE, 
                options = list(
                  columnDefs = list(
                    list(
                      className = 'dt-center', 
                      targets = "_all"
                    )
                  )
                ), 
                colnames = c("A", "mult_A", "add_A"))
    })
    
  })
}
```

Module 2:

```
updateData <- function(df, svc) {
  mult_A <- df[, "mult_A"]
  add_A <- mult_A + 10
  updatedData <- cbind(df, add_A)
  updatedData
}
```